# git clone loads wrong SSH-Key (Windows)

Tags: git, ssh

I was invited to a company project on github and I'm trying to clone the project. But another email/github account was invited to that project. Now when I'm trying to clone the project, I get the following output:

```
git clone git@github.com:XXX/YYY.git .      
Cloning into '.'...
load pubkey "/c/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
Load key "/c/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.      

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

I created before a new rsa key. The file is called: `id_rsa_xxx` & `id_rsa_xxx.pub` and added the pub rsa key to my second github account.

But as you can see in my console output, my console is loading the public and private key named: `id_rsa` and not `id_rsa_xxx`

And I have no clue how to change it just for this project. For all my other projects, the `id_rsa` file is the right one.

I also added the `id_rsa_xxx` with "`ssh-add`" by using the "`ssh-agent`" before.

Any clue? I mostly find mac OS answers but nothing so far that helped me for windows. I also don't have a "config" file inside the .ssh folder.

Comment: Git-for-Windows comes with an ssh implementation (because Windows didn't, once) and Windows comes with an ssh implementation now and the two implementations don't talk to each other, so check whether your Git is running the system ssh or the private ssh. (These will use different `.ssh` directories, probably.) Then create or update an appropriate `.ssh/config` if/as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As torek already mentioned, you can create a new entry in your [~/.ssh/config file](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/), which could look something like this:

```
Host your_preffered_name_here
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_xxx
```

Next try again: `git clone your_preffered_name_here:XXX/YYY.git`

PS: I'm not sure if the *User git* option is really required